# Сделать заголовок pyqt QComboBox

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Мне нужно сделать что то на подобии такого:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Название самого Combo бокса "Точка доступу до Інтернету" но при этом в списке обьектов которые мы можем выбрать нету этого названия и мне необходиомо сделать так

Comment: Это называется placeholderText https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcombobox.html#placeholderText-prop

Comment: спасибо большое!